# List past hours of today with django

Tags: python, django

How do I create a list of past hours of the day?

I tried this but it only gets the past 12 hours, and what if the past hour is from yesterday?

```py
past_hours = []
for x in range(12):
past_hours.append((date - datetime.timedelta(hours=x)))
```

Comment: If you execute your code at `01:00 AM' you get yestarday hours. I vote to close.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of datetimes of the start of every hour since the start of the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're after:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
day = now.day
month = now.month
year = now.year

hours_since_midnight = now.hour
hours = []

# Via a for loop
for i in range(hours_since_midnight):
    hours.append(datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=i))

# Or you can do it this way (list comprehension)
hours = [datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=x)
         for x in range(hours_since_midnight)]
```

This will create a list of date-times of the start of every hour since the start of the day (**not including the current hour**). If you want the current hour, you need to do `range(hours_since_midnight + 1)`

Comment: You can compress `day`,`month` and `year` straight into your definitions if you'd like too

Comment: I tried something similar which produce a list of time from past 24 hours (excludes yesterday)

`past_hours = []
    for x in range(24):
        date_test = date_today - datetime.timedelta(hours=x)
        if(date_today.day>date_test.day):
            pass
        else:
            past_hours.append((date_today - datetime.timedelta(hours=x)).strftime("%I:%M %p"))`

but this still works, thanks!

Comment: No worries, check out [this website](http://strftime.net/) too, it's real good for time strings